# Azure Web SItes - how to write to a file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, abcpdf, azure-web-app-service

I am using abcPDF to dynamically create PDFs.

I want to save these PDFs for clients to retrieve any time they want. The easiest way (and the way I do now on my current server) is to simply save the finished PDF to the file system.

Seems I am stuck with using blobs. Luckily abcPDF can save to a stream as well as a file. Now, how to I wire up a stream to a blob? I have found code that shows the blob taking a stream like:

```
blob.UploadFromStream(theStream, options);
```

The abcPDF function looks like this:

```
theDoc.Save(theStream)
```

I do not know how to bridge this gap.

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the situation and not knowing the full list of overloads of Save() method of abcPdf, it seems that you need a MemoryStream. Something like:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    theDoc.Save(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    blob.UploadFromStream(ms, options);
}
```

This shall do the job. But if you are dealing with big files, and you are expecting a lot of traffic (lots of simultaneous PDF creations), you might just go for a temp file. Write the PDF to a temp file, then immediatelly upload the temp file for the blob.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. How would I save a temp file? It seems if I could do that I could just save the original file. I can't change the permissions on the local folders, so no writing files, sorry I did not make that part very clear in my post.

Comment: Yup, that surely did work. I think I am going to play with Azure CloudDrive as well. That simulates an NTFS volume. I have another third party control that will only save a file :(.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative that doesn't require holding the entire file in memory, you might try this:

```
using (var stream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    theDoc.Save(stream);
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding a caveat here: if the `save` method requires a seekable stream, I don't think this will work.

Comment: Ooh, nice. I will have a chance to try that out next week when I get back to this project.

Comment: Added an edit about seekable streams... you may still have to use an intermediary like a `MemoryStream` if the `save` method needs to seek.